# Restrict a user if too many attempt laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to block a user for an hour if he/She enters a wrong product code 5 times while submitting their personal detail at the same time. how can I achieve it?

Comment: use `throttle:5,1` middleware builtin laravel

Comment: but I want to do it for specific users that attempt 5 times

Comment: yes it is user specific  please read doc

Comment: i mean i have a user detail while submitting the form and i wnanna block by the mobile number that is submiting along with the form, the mobile number create a profile in customerproile table in my database